# jquery fullCalendar - get day type from database and color specific date when calander load

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the latest version of jQuery full calendar. I want to color specific days in my calendar using separate colors when the calendar is initially loading (not when the event is loading). I keep dates with color codes in a separate MySQL database table.

Here is an example of what the interface should look like:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4YRdfCv-ciIQ0w2djVFMXB0ODg

I'm currently stuck. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month'//'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    fixedWeekCount:false,
    businessHours: false,
    editable: false,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    loading: function (bool) {
        if (bool) {
            $('#loading').show();
        } else {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    }
    events: {
        url: '/leave/load_events',
        data: function () { // a function that returns an object
            return {
                employee_id: $('#employee_id').val()
            };
        }
    },
    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
        showPopup();
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        element.find('.fc-title').append(event.description);

    }
});
```

Comment: @Michael0x2a thanks for corrections.

Comment: Anyone have a idea bout this. I want to color day background when change employee combo without page reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but here is some examples of coloring days: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/9rxrx4fb/27/)

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    dayRender:function(date, cell){ //change day cell to red every time the day cells are rendered
        cell.css("background-color","red");
    },
    dayClick:function(){ //change days to white when you click on them
        console.log(this);
        $(this).css("background-color","white");
    },
});
$("body > button").on("click",function(){ //when the green or yellow button is pushed, change a specific date's color.
    $(".fc-bg .fc-day").filter(function(index,day){
        if($(day).data("date")==="2015-08-02")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }).css("background-color",$(this).data("color"));
})
```

Let me know if I missed something.